# Issue with query in DB2 --Not able to find the cause

Tags: sql, db2

I was trying to execute the below query in Db2 and its giving me some error, which I am not able to identify the root cause.Could someone please help here.

```
with
  test as(
  select * from (
    select
      ID,SOURCE,NUMBERD
     from TABLE where RND='4')t (ID,SOURCE,NUMBERD)
     ),
  t as (
    select
      ID,
      count(*) qnt,
      count(distinct SOURCE) distinct_qnt,
      count(distinct NUMBERD) NUMBERD_CNT,
      sum(case when SOURCE = 'EXTERNAL' then 1 else 0 END) external_qnt,
      sum(case when SOURCE <> 'EXTERNAL' then 1 else 0 END) internal_qnt
    from test
    group by ID
  )

    delete from TABLE where RND='4' and ID in(
    select ID from(
    select
    ID,
    case when (external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt or NUMBERD_CNT >1) then 3
    when (external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt and internal_qnt=0) then 2 else 1 END scenario_id
    from t where case when (external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt or NUMBERD_CNT >1) then 3
            when (external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt and internal_qnt=0) then 2 else 1 END in(2,3))asd)
```

The error which I am getting when executing the above query is

> `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=delete from;by
>   qsMatchSetID   ) ;<from>, DRIVER=3.58.81`

But if I comment the delete portion alone and execute the query it is working fine, something like below.

```
        with
  test as(
            ...............
            ...........
                from test
        group by ID
      )
    --delete from TABLE where RND='4' and ID in(
    select ID from(
    select
    ID,
    case when (external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt or NUMBERD_CNT >1) then 3
    when (external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt and internal_qnt=0) then 2 else 1 END scenario_id
    from t where case when (external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt or NUMBERD_CNT >1) then 3
            when (external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt and internal_qnt=0) then 2 else 1 END in(2,3))
            ---asd)
```

Comment: You can't use a CTE in a `DELETE` statement; convert it to a subselect.

Comment: Okay I tried something like that, but still getting the same error. "delete from TABLE where RND='4' and ID in(
select ID from(
select
ID,
case when (external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt or NUMBERD_CNT >1) then 3
when (external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt and internal_qnt=0) then 2 else 1 END scenario_id
from t)a where scenario_id in(2,3))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [data-change-table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html?view=kc#r0059206__dctr) of subselect, if you want to use CTE for the data change statement.

```
declare global temporary table session.table (rnd varchar(10), id int, SOURCE varchar(10), NUMBERD int) 
with replace on commit preserve rows not logged;

with
  test as
(
  select * 
  from 
  (
    select ID, SOURCE, NUMBERD
    from SESSION.TABLE 
    where RND='4'
  ) t (ID,SOURCE,NUMBERD)
 )
 , t as 
 (
    select
      ID,
      count(*) qnt,
      count(distinct SOURCE) distinct_qnt,
      count(distinct NUMBERD) NUMBERD_CNT,
      sum(case when SOURCE = 'EXTERNAL' then 1 else 0 END) external_qnt,
      sum(case when SOURCE <> 'EXTERNAL' then 1 else 0 END) internal_qnt
    from test
    group by ID
)

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM OLD TABLE 
(
  delete from SESSION.TABLE 
  where RND='4' and ID in
  (
    select ID 
    from
    (
    select
      ID
    , case 
        when (external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt or NUMBERD_CNT >1) then 3
        when (external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt and internal_qnt=0) then 2 else 1 
      END scenario_id
    from t 
    where 
      case 
        when (external_qnt = 0 or external_qnt = qnt or NUMBERD_CNT >1) then 3
        when (external_qnt = 1 and distinct_qnt = qnt and internal_qnt=0) then 2 
        else 1 
      END in (2,3)
    ) asd
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the query Mark.I tried using this, but still its throwing me the same error

Comment: @GIN I've changed the example to run it as is. If it doesn't work for you, then what's your Db2 platform and version?

Comment: We are using DB2 10.5 which is hosted in linux server

Comment: What’s the exact error message, when you run 2 statements above in the same session **as is**?

Comment: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=FROM OLD TABLE
(
  delete;
)

SELECT COUNT(1)
;<space>, DRIVER=3.58.81...this is the error I am getting when running the your query

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=f5c917151b21cd811ba465033a3db56c) example. The same works on my 10.5.10 on Linux. What's the result of `select versionnumber, versionbuildlevel from sysibm.sysversions` in your system?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205577/discussion-between-mark-barinstein-and-gin).